# Why would the Netflix App want to "read sensitive log data" on my device?

Tags: permissions, netflix

I just noticed that that [Netflix App](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.netflix.mediaclient) wants the "Read Sensitive Log Data" permission to run.

- What exactly does this permission allow? (besides the fairly generic/scary sounding description in the market)
- Why do you think the Netflix app might need it?

Comment: Maybe you should contact the developer and ask them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some apps use this to retrieve debug information and send it to the company to help improve the app (eg. Evernote [[source]](https://support.evernote.com/link/portal/16051/16058/Article/536/Overview-of-Android-Permissions-and-Data-Usage)). Couldn't find any information on how Netflix uses the data and can't test but maybe there's a "Send debug information" button or something similar. This, of course, is pure speculation, so you'll have to think "Do I trust this company with my data?"

As to what information is made available by this, you can check this by using [aLogcat](https://market.android.com/details?id=org.jtb.alogcat) or the Android SDK and [logcat](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/logcat.html). There's a public Google+ [post](https://plus.google.com/116531573955215493775/posts/Kqu7Uf38tih) which describes an example of logcat information.

Comment: That Google+ link is dead